# Workflow for sending email in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, email, excel

Is there any way to get an excel export from a SharePoint list and email to users in SharePoint 2010?

We have a list which update weekly and I want to email all users in format of Excel

Comment: Do you want to do this by a workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Default Functionality of export to excel for list is Awesome, but according to me the same cannot be call through any API. So I would suggest rather than Workflow, go with SharePoint Timer Job feature.

This link would help you do the same and achieve your functionality

http://bhatiaashish.blogspot.in/2012/09/export-to-excel-and-email-sharepoint.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc427068(v=office.12).aspx

You can also achieve the same functionality using PowerShell code to export the list to Excel file and then send email to the mail adress, and use the Windows Task Scheduler to trigger the above PowerShell code daily/weekly/monthly, please see more from posts below.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/f138f724-aa31-41b3-abc3-d8768e888893/script-to-export-a-sharepoint-2010-list-view-and-send-to-recipients

http://get-spscripts.com/2011/01/running-sharepoint-powershell-script.html

Comment: thank you I want to use the code of http://bhatiaashish.blogspot.in/2012/09/export-to-excel-and-email-sharepoint.html     but how can i activate it on my web application  is there any manual ?

Comment: because as I know we need wsp file to deploy  but there is not any .wsp file

Comment: Bhatia Ashish blog will help you achieve thefunctionality you need. And neccessary steps needed to deploy and activate timer job can be found here.
http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-procedures-to-create-a-Timer-Job-in-SharePoint-2013

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/634208/Create-and-Deploy-Custom-Timer-Job-Definition-in-S

Comment: thank you your first link contain a source code how can I use that                 http://bhatiaashish.blogspot.in/2012/09/export-to-excel-and-email-sharepoint.html there is a solution and I donnot know how to use that  best regards